# How to implement recursively the Chebyshev polynomials in Sagemath?

Tags: python, recursion, sage

I found on
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Definition)
a formula to calculate the
**Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind**
in a recursiv way:

`T₀(x) = 1`
`T₁(x) = x`
`Tₙ(x) = (Tₙ₊₁(x) + Tₙ₋₁(x)) / 2x`

However I am actually not shure how to implement it in Sagemath.

```
def T(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    else:
        t = (T(n+1) + T(n-1)) / (2*x)
    return t
```

When `n` is 2 or greater I always get a RuntimeError, meaning my recursion never stops. I understand the Principe of a recursion and the difference to an iterative process, but I am bit stuck here.

The intended output would be:

```
sage: T(0)
1
sage: T(1)
x
sage: T(2)
2x^2 - 1
sage: T(3)
4x^3 - 3x
sage: # and so on
```

Comment: if `T(2)` depends on `T(3)` and `T(3)` on `T(4)` and so on, how do you expect this to ever finish? Do not solve for `T(n)` Assume that n = n+1 and re-arrange..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are interpreting the rule wrong. There is no need to solve for `T(n)`. Just assume `n = n + 1` and the last recurrence relation becomes: `T(n) = 2xT(n-1) - T(n-2)`. So your recursive function becomes:

```
def T(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return x
    else:
        return 2 * x * T(n-1) - T(n-2)
```

Which gives the desired result.

---

Example:

```
T(2) = 2x * T(1) - T(0)
```

but `T(1) = x` and `T(0) = 1`, so:

```
T(2) = 2x * x - 1
T(2) = 2x^2 - 1
```

Comment: Now I understand, thx! (By the way: there has to be a minus between the first and second term: `Tₙ(x) = 2xTₙ₋₁(x) - Tₙ₋₂(x)` in the last line `return 2 * x * T(n-1) - T(n-2)` instead of the plus, like you mentioned correctly in your text above ;)

Comment: One last question; Is there a way to convert the result to a clearer representation? 
`T(4)` for example results in `2*(2*(2*x^2 - 1)*x - x)*x - 2*x^2 + 1`, 
while it can be reduced to `8*x^4 - 8*x^2 + 1`. 
I already tried `simplify(T(4))`, unfortunately this results in the same representation ...

Comment: @PatrickSteiner I am not familiar with `sage` unfortunately but maybe [`simplify_full()`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109136/simplify-function-of-sage) helps? Otherwise, you can try [`sympy`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html)

Comment: `T(4).simplify_full()` works fine for me, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear, [Chebyshev polynomials](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/orthogonal_polys.html) and friends of various kinds are implemented in SageMath.